# Add attribute on @XmlElementWrapper

Tags: java, moxy

I have this code below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FNOL")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ConversationXML {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "ParticipantList")
    @XmlElement(name = "Participant")
    List<ParticipantsXML> participantList;
    @XmlElement
    KeyActionsXML keyActions;
    @XmlElement
    LossDetailsXML lossDetails;
    @XmlElement
    AdditionalLossDetailsXML addLossDetails;
    @XmlElement
    PolicyDetailsXML policyDetails;

    //getter setter

}
```

and I want to add an attribute to the ParticipantList element

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FNOL>
    <ParticipantList>
        <Participant inv="" v="" pid="" id=""/>
    </ParticipantList>
    <keyActions inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
    <lossDetails inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
    <addLossDetails inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
    <policyDetails inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
</FNOL>
```

like this one but i have no idea how to do it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<FNOL>
    <ParticipantList inv="" v="" pid="" id="">
        <Participant inv="" v="" pid="" id=""/>
    </ParticipantList>
    <keyActions inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
    <lossDetails inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
    <addLossDetails inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
    <policyDetails inv="" v="" pid="" id="11"/>
</FNOL>
```

Can someone help me with this one :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, really.

The real solution is to create your participantList as a class of itself.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "FNOL")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class ConversationXML {

    @XmlElement
    ParticipantList participantList;
    @XmlElement
    KeyActionsXML keyActions;
    @XmlElement
    LossDetailsXML lossDetails;
    @XmlElement
    AdditionalLossDetailsXML addLossDetails;
    @XmlElement
    PolicyDetailsXML policyDetails;

    //getter setter

}

public class ParticipantList {

    @XmlElement(name = "Participant")
    List<ParticipantsXML> participants;

    @XmlAttribute 
    String inv;

    @XmlAttribute
    String v;

    ...
}
```

(nitpick: 'v' is a really poor attribute name; if your xml format is fixed, use a different name for your field in java, then set  the name in the annotation)